# I can install packages in R only opening R from the desktop

Tags: r

I have this problem. 
I have installed "R x64 3.5.2" on Windows 10 and created a shortcut on my desktop to open it.
If I open R from the shortcut I can install packages without problems, and R saves all the packages in the folder C:\Users\Name_of_my_user\RtmpGCLl28.
If I open R from the folder where R is installed (the same that the shortcut should open) I can't find the libraries that I previously installed and in addition to that I cannot install packages and R returns these lines:

> Errore: unable to create temporary directory
>   ‘C:\Users\Name_of_the_user\Documents\R\win-library\3.5\file14a830d675c9’
>   Inoltre: Warning message: In dir.create(tmpDir) :   cannot create dir
>   'C:\Users\Name_of_the_user\Documents\R\win-library\3.5\file14a830d675c9',
>   reason 'No such file or directory'

How can I fix this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Does directory 'C:\Users\Name_of_the_user\Documents\R\win-library\3.5‘ exist?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's a permission-related error. Try "Run as administrator" option. 
Also, following solutions maybe work for you: 
[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44953046/rstudio-unexpected-call-to-dir-create-with-the-first-instruction-within-a-p) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059692/unable-to-update-r-packages-in-default-library-on-windows-7) [[3]](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/RRO/issues/144) [[4]](https://github.com/swirldev/swirl/issues/60)